# Make a transparent <div> opaque to mouse events

Tags: html, click, transparent

I think I asked about the opposite problem a while ago (allow mouse event to pass through a transparent area on an image - I ended up using an imagemap for that) but anyway:

I need a mask element for when a dialog comes up. In the past I've used:

```
position:fixed;
left:0;top:0;right:0;bottom:0;
background:#000000;
opacity:0;
filter:alpha(opacity=0);
```

And it works, but it's kind of a "hack".

I've not been able to get an element with `background:transparent` to intercept mouse events. Is this intentional? Is there any way around this other than the above? Or is the above the best solution for this problem?

Comment: A jsfiddle demo showing `background:transparent` not working would be helpful. It seemed to work fine either way in the limited testing I did in FF and IE.

Comment: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/5LM2F/) - you should not be able to click on the button, but you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with `background:transparent` appears to be specific to IE (tested in IE7/8/9). It's not an issue in other browsers.

It's also specific to HTML form elements. For instance, it works fine in IE for text inside a paragraph tag but not for a button tag. Most likely it's a rendering bug in IE, rather than the result of a deliberate engineering decision by Microsoft. There used to be a similar issue in IE6 with select boxes not layering correctly with `position:absolute`.

It'd be safer to use `opacity` than `background:transparent` in this case. It may feel less like a hack if you change the `opacity` of the mask to make it partially transparent instead of fully transparent.